# How to return three numbers in a function without using array or pointer in C?

Tags: c, function

The question:

Write a program that accepts three integers and then prints them in the order read and reversed. Use three functions, one to read the data, one to print them in the order read and one to print in reverse order.

The program (not finished):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int accept(){
    int x, y, z;
    printf("Please enter three integers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    return x, y, z;
}

int main(){
    x, y, z = accept();
}
```

Errors:
  error: 'x' undeclared (first use in this function)|
  note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it 
  appears in|
  error: 'y' undeclared (first use in this function)|
  error: 'z' undeclared (first use in this function)|

How can I modify this program so that I can return the three variables without using arrays or pointers? Or is it impossible without using those?

Comment: as I know, it is impossible.

Comment: Is there some reason not to use a pointer?  You could return a struct, or use global variables.

Comment: Since you have only one return value, that approach will need an aggregate (array or struct).  You can have multiple arguments, but using an argument to return requires a pointer.  Or as William said, you can pass data out of a function using global variables (but this is the worst options).

Comment: You can trivially do this if the function has no side-effects. Simply pass an extra parameter that specifies which of the variables you want. Then call the function once for each variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a struct that contains those three values

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int a, b, c;
} MyStruct;
```

Then pass a pointer to the struct instance to and from the function (side note: ALWAYS do this with a pointer as it is more efficient because it only passes an 8 byte value. Passing the struct itself means (if I remember correctly) the compiler will attempt to split the struct into it's values when passing it as an argument)

Comment: Compilers are getting much more efficient and can optimize the heck out of returning objects from functions by value.  That wasn't the case when I was first starting out many years ago.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to build the struct and return it from the function by value.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to read about it more. That was just from knowledge from my professor when I took my first course in C. But then again, we did everything in ansi C90, so it may have been old standards. But I still stand by my comment. Since there's no harming in passing pointers

Comment: Note that any optimization concerns regarding any potential copies not elided during `return` are completely bogus when you're using `printf` to prompt on stdout and reading integers from stdin.  Not to mention the answer here is recommending a single pointer copy plus 3 pointer indirections versus _maybe_ three integer copies from the stack at worst.

Comment: Yes, I guess for this case it would be unnecessary since it's only three integers, but for hypothetical reasons. Disregard the OP code. Would you then say it would be appropriate for a struct of say 50 different values?

Comment: *ALWAYS do this with a pointer as it is more efficient because it only passes an 8 byte value.* That ignores where the source of the memory referred to by the pointer comes from.  Returning a pointer to a structure pretty much means that the structure itself has to be allocated with `malloc()` or similar and then `free()`'d later else the function likely won't be MT-safe nor reentrant.  That can also be immensely less efficient than simply returning the structure by value *and* using `malloc()` makes the function non-async-signal-safe. Even 50 values is likely faster than `malloc()`/`free()`.

Answer (score 0):

Expansion of my comment. This is **not** sensible code and **not recommended** in practice but it is one way to amend your code to implement the requirement of multiple return values without arrays or pointers (or structs).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int accept(char opt){
    /* static variables remember their values between calls */
    static int x, y, z;

    if (opt=='x') return x;
    if (opt=='y') return y;
    if (opt=='z') return z;

    /* any other value of opt, read in new values */
    printf("Please enter three integers: \n");
    return scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
}

int main(){
    int x, y, z;
    accept(' ');
    x = accept('x');
    y = accept('y');
    z = accept('z');
}
```

Comment: Oh no.  Ewww.  No.

Comment: @paddy agreed. just can't help responding to people saying things are impossible... :-)

Comment: Okay, but don't you think it's plain irresponsible to promote a solution like this?